# My js pagination code is not working, completely lost as to what is causing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have a pagination set up that I have used many time before... works great for lists and simple paragraphs, but I am unable to get it to work with a more complex html code, which is listed below. For some reason, the js refuses to turn the below code into a set object in order to paginate.

```
<div class="properties-content">
    <div id="paging_container8" class="container">
        <div class="storybody">
            <p>
                <!---------- Property Start ---------->
                <article class="hentry">
                    <div class="property-featured"> <a class="content-thumb" href="property-details.html"> <img src="images/property/property3.jpg" alt=""> </a> <span class="property-label last">Last one left</span> <span class="property-category"><a href="#">Single Family Home</a> </span> </div>
                    <div class="property-wrap">
                        <h2 class="property-title"> <a href="property-details.html" title="Single Family Residential, NJ">Single Family Residential, NJ</a> </h2>
                        <div class="property-excerpt">
                            <p>Classic 60's ranch living. House has hardwood floors and hard coat plaster walls and ceilings...</p>
                            <p class="property-fullwidth-excerpt">Classic 60's ranch living. House has hardwood floors and hard coat plaster walls and ceilings in good condition. Intimate backyard for private gatherings. Full basement...</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="property-summary">
                            <div class="property-detail">
                                <div class="size"> <span>1118 sqft</span> </div>
                                <div class="bathrooms"> <span>2</span> </div>
                                <div class="bedrooms"> <span>3</span> </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="property-info">
                                <div class="property-price"> <span> <span class="amount">&#36;299,000</span> </span> </div>
                                <div class="property-action"> <a href="property-details.html">More Details</a> </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="property-info property-fullwidth-info">
                                <div class="property-price"> <span><span class="amount">&#36;299,000</span> </span> </div>
                                <div class="size"><span>1118 sqft</span> </div>
                                <div class="bathrooms"><span>2</span> </div>
                                <div class="bedrooms"><span>3</span> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="property-action property-fullwidth-action"> <a href="property-details.html">More Details</a> </div>
                </article>
                <!---------- Property End ----------> 
                <!---------- Property End ---------->
            </p>

            <div class="page_navigation"></div>
```

I need, due to how my css is, to show 2 of the above code snippet out of maybe 25. And here is my javascript that I am using:

```
<script>
var str= $(".storybody").html();
var substr=str.split( "<!--pagebreak-->" );
var txt="<ul class='storycontent'><li>";
var x=0;
for (x in substr)
  {
    if(x==0){
        txt=txt+substr[x];
    }
    else{
          txt=txt+"</li><li>"+substr[x];
    }
  }
var paginated=txt+"</li></ul>";
$('div.storybody').replaceWith(paginated);

$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#paging_container8').pajinate({
                    num_page_links_to_display : 2,
                    items_per_page : 1 ,
                    item_container_id : '.storycontent'
                });
            });
​</script>
```

And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moLwmyyr/1/

Comment: Off topic: Nested paragraphs are not valid HTML.

Comment: Works != valid. You should care about the quality of your code.

Comment: A simple fix would be to change the outer `p` tag to a `div` tag and reapply any CSS needed to maintain your layout.

Comment: Oh, I've done that. I had the outer <p> tags due to that was how the js code was written to accept, and could not work with <div> tags. Now that I have it fixed, I have it set up as a <div class> instead of a <p>

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out!

The following js, along with the js in the fiddle, work with my html code in my question. Instead of the original js which only worked for simple lists, tables, and paragraphs, the js listed here will work on nested html code.

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".pagination").customPaginate({

        itemsToPaginate : ".post"

    });

    });

})(jQuery)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moLwmyyr/2/

Works perfectly with my site and css. Hope this helps others.